# CheckNullability of PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

Tags: hibernate, join, null, transient, one-to-one

I have a Entity class that has the ObjectX attribute:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public ClassOfObjectX getObjectX() {
return this.ObjectX;
}
```

This ObjectX can´t be null?

In Hibernate 3.4 I could save this object in the repository without any problem
but now in Hibernate 3.6 it´s throwing this exception:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value:
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if it works when you set the property
`hibernate.check_nullability` to false?